# How to run code again using shortcut keys in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I ran my code using the shortcut keys and I ran for the first time. Then I wanted to run the code again, so I pressed the keys again to run but it doesn't run. Rather it types whatever keys I'm pressing. It does run the code by pressing the run button provided by code runner. Can someone please tell me what to do to run code using the keys only, without needing to use my mouse to click the run button?

Comment: what is the `when` clause of the used key-binding

Comment: i havent added the when command..can you please me what should i put in it? I've just started using vs code.

Comment: if you tell us where you see the `keys I'm pressing`, and what is the key binding combo

Comment: I've set alt+n  for run code

Comment: and where do you see `Alt+n` when you press the key-binding, have you tried the key-binding debugging to see what VSC does with the key press

Comment: when i press the keys for assigned to debugging , it isn't debugging properly

Comment: you say: `Rather it types whatever keys im pressing.` Where do you see this?